# AutoQuery is not getting the name db connection when run through gateway

Tags: servicestack

I have an implementation, where I am calling an autoquery operation via the service gateway. The service gateway will successfully call both internal and external operations.  However, any autoquery operation fails because it is not getting the connection string set.  These same autoquery operations work just fine when called directly and not through the gateway.

Here is the stack trace.

```
at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnectionFactory.CreateDbConnection() in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\27e4cc16641be8c0\\src\\ServiceStack.OrmLite\\OrmLiteConnectionFactory.cs:line 70\r\n   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection() in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\27e4cc16641be8c0\\src\\ServiceStack.OrmLite\\OrmLiteConnectionFactory.cs:line 95\r\n   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.GetDbConnection(IRequest req) in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\3481147c480f4a2f\\src\\ServiceStack\\ServiceStackHost.Runtime.cs:line 691\r\n   at ServiceStack.AutoQuery.GetDb(Type type, IRequest req) in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\3481147c480f4a2f\\src\\ServiceStack.Server\\AutoQueryFeature.cs:line 598\r\n   at ServiceStack.AutoQuery.CreateQuery[From](IQueryDb`1 dto, Dictionary`2 dynamicParams, IRequest req) in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\3481147c480f4a2f\\src\\ServiceStack.Server\\AutoQueryFeature.cs:line 608\r\n   at IDOE.SecurityPortal.Api.ServiceInterface.OrganizationUserStaffTypeService.Get(QueryOrganizationUserStaffTypes query) in E:\\source\\repos\\Azure - Security Portal\\src\\IDOE.SecurityPortal\\IDOE.SecurityPortal.Api.ServiceInterface\\OrganizationUserStaffTypeService.cs:line 47\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\3481147c480f4a2f\\src\\ServiceStack\\Host\\ServiceRunner.cs:line 133
```

Database Connection Registration in startup.cs

```
    var dbFacotry = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>();
    dbFacotry.RegisterConnection("SecPortal", AppSettings.Get<string>("SQLSERVER-SECPORTAL-CONNECTIONSTRING"), SqlServer2017Dialect.Provider);
    dbFacotry.RegisterConnection("EdfiMdm", AppSettings.Get<string>("SQLSERVER-EDFIMDM-CONNECTIONSTRING"), SqlServer2017Dialect.Provider);

    Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature { IncludeTotal = true });
```

AutoQuery Definition

```
[Authenticate]
[RequiredClaim("scope", "secprtl-read")]
[Route("/files", Verbs = "GET")]
[ConnectionInfo(NamedConnection = "SecPortal")]
public class QueryFiles : QueryDb<Types.File>
{
    [QueryDbField(Field = "Id", Template = "({Value} IS NULL OR {Field} = {Value})")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Field = "FileName", Template = "({Value} IS NULL OR UPPER({Field}) LIKE UPPER({Value}))", ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Field = "UserId", Template = "({Value} IS NULL OR UPPER({Field}) LIKE UPPER({Value}))", ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Field = "StateOrganizationId", Template = "({Value} IS NULL OR UPPER({Field}) LIKE UPPER({Value}))", ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
    public string StateOrganizationId { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Field = "Notes", Template = "({Value} IS NULL OR UPPER({Field}) LIKE UPPER({Value}))", ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Code calling the service

```
public class ContactService : Service
{

    public ContactService()
    {
    }

    public async Task<object> Post(PostContact request)
    {
        try
        {
            var files = base.Gateway.Send(new QueryFiles() { });

            return new Contact() { Name = request.Name };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }


}
```

Custom Service Gateway

```
public class CustomServiceGatewayFactory : ServiceGatewayFactoryBase
{

    private IRequest request;

    public override IServiceGateway GetServiceGateway(IRequest request)
    {
        this.request = request;
        return base.GetServiceGateway(request);
    }

    public override IServiceGateway GetGateway(Type requestType)
    {
        var isLocal = HostContext.Metadata.RequestTypes.Contains(requestType);

        if (isLocal)
        {
            return base.localGateway;
        }
        else
        {
            return new JsonServiceClient("https://localhost:6001")
            {
                BearerToken = request.GetBearerToken()
            };
        }
    }

}
```

Custom service gateway registration in startup.cs

```
container.Register<IServiceGatewayFactory>(x => new CustomServiceGatewayFactory()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);
```

The call being made in the service class is a local call. Calling an external service that uses autoquery works just fine. I can also call the local service directly with no problem.

---

I created a custom autoquery method in the service interface, I noticed that the db connection info was not populated on the request.items array.  So I manually added that information to the request, and it worked as expected.  So somehow, in my setup, the autoquery operations that are called locally, the db connection info is not getting added to the request object.

Comment: Can you please provide more info to show the request that's causing an Error. Please include the AutoQuery definition including how the DB is configured, the code you're using to send the Gateway request and whether the Gateway request is to a remote or local service.

Comment: See my updates above.  I added all the relevant code.  Calling the operation directly over http works just fine, calling it using the service gateway causes the connection string error.  Calling a remote service via the gateway that uses autoquery works just fine.

Comment: The `[ConnectionInfo]` attribute works by adding the connection to use in the `IRequest.Items[Keywords.DbInfo]` dictionary. Can you override `GetDbConnection(req)` in your AppHost and tell me what `req.GetType()` is and whether `req.GetItem(Keywords.DbInfo)` returns anything.

Comment: Type = {Name = "NetCoreRequest" FullName = "ServiceStack.Host.NetCore.NetCoreRequest"}

req.GetItem is null

Comment: ok so it means the `[ConnectionInfo]` Request Filter attribute was never applied because it's not annotated on the Service that calls the Service gateway.

Comment: It overrides the DB Info for that Request, but if you call `Db` in your Service before overriding it, it's still remains configured with its db configuration, even after it's overridden. You can also hold `req.GetItem(Keywords.DbInfo)` then reset it again after calling the Service Gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Request Filter Attributes](https://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes) like `[ConnectionInfo]` is only applied on HTTP Requests, not internal Service Gateway requests.

The Connection info isn't configured because it's not annotated on your `PostContact` Service Request DTO that calls the in-procces Service Gateway.

You can have the `[ConnectionInfo]` on the `QueryFiles` [AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery) Request DTO attached to the current Request with:

```
public async Task<object> Post(PostContact request)
{
    try
    {
        typeof(QueryFiles).FirstAttribute<ConnectionInfoAttribute>()
            .Execute(Request,Response,request);

        var files = base.Gateway.Send(new QueryFiles() { });

        return new Contact() { Name = request.Name };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```